# Download an XML BDC file from a Sharepoint server

Tags: sharepoint-2007, bdc

There's a BDC xml application file in the server done by another programmer. Is there a way to download the file back to my PC? SO, I can review it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to SharedServices. Under Business Data Catalog Section go to View applications. Click on the application definition you want to download. Then select Export Application Definition.